# How to Get Access to Page's Script Context

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

My addon uses a content script to interact with the page.  But it also needs access to the page's javascript so it can run one of the page's routines.  So my content script needs access to the page's script context.

Here's what I mean.

Addon uses main.js which access content.js and uses messaging to communicate.

But the web-page (into which content.js is being injected) has it's own javascript.  My content.js needs access to that context so it can fetch the values from variables there.

How can one get that?

I have [been reading these mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts), but it seems like they are talking about an html page that you code yourself, like you would for a preferences page.  But in my case I am working with an external website, not something coded just for the addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach [listed on the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts#Access_objects_defined_by_page_scripts) also works for external pages, not just your own.

I.e. `unsafeWindow.myPageVar` will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = "alert( myPageVar );";
document.body.appendChild( script );
```

[Credit goes to this fellow](http://louisremi.com/2011/12/07/mozilla-addons-interactions-between-content-scripts-and-pages/).

I don't know whether this is the best way to do this, however.  I hope that someone else more knowledgeable than me will answer.

Here's how to return a value:

```
var retval = unsafeWindow.SomePageFunction();
alert(retval);
```

It's called "unsafe" because you never know what about the page might be changed or might change.  That's how it when the addon [interacts with page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts).